# nil on conversion string to date

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try to convert string to date

my method looks like this

```
func createDateFromString(string: String) -> NSDate {

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"//this your string date format
    let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(string)

    return date!
}
```

But I have a runtime a error.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

String is not empty :

[image]

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your date format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

Comment: If you solve your problem, please tell us accepting the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You should just remove `.SSS` from `dateFormat` and implicit unwrapping to avoid fatal error (function should return optional value).
[image: Playground]

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"//this your string date format
```