# Swift DateFormatter returns nil while converting String to Date

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a string:

`2018-01-18 13:04:42 +0000`

to something like

`January, 18, 2018`

using `DateFormatter` but it fails. I have tried other questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328577/dateformatter-returns-nil), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42756031/coverstion-from-string-to-date-in-swift-returns-nil) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986288/nil-on-conversion-string-to-date)).

This is my simple code which prints `nil`:

```
let str = "2018-01-18 13:04:42 +0000" 
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, dd, YYYY" 
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current 
let mydate = dateFormatter.date(from: str) 
print(mydate)
```

Comment: The provided string does not contain a *single* comma. This is a pretty clear reason for failure in its own.

Comment: @the4kman What does it have to with a comma? would you please tell me why you thumb it down?!

Comment: `2018-01-18 13:04:42 +0000" ` vs `"MM, dd, YYYY" `. In which word the format look like the string? None. You need to use the format used by the string, then convert it to date, then use your target format `"MM, dd, YYYY"` and transform that date into the target string.

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM, dd, YYYY" ` this line tells the dateFormatter what format the string is in that you are *reading*, not what output you want. you first need to convert the string date into a Date object.

Comment: @Maysam You have to use the format as used in the string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `DateFormatter` expects the original string to be in the `January, 18, 2018` format. You should convert it to a `Date` first and only convert it to another format **after** that.

Also, you should not use `YYYY` when referring to an ordinary calendar year. [See this question for details.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15133549/3151675)

```swift
let str = "2018-01-18 13:04:42 +0000" 
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" 
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") 

guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str) else {
    return
}

let newDateFormatter = DateFormatter() 
newDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMMM, dd, yyyy" 
let newStr = newDateFormatter.string(from: date)
print(newStr) /*January, 18, 2018*/
```

Comment: The locale is `en_US_POSIX`, not `EN_US_POSIX`.

Comment: @the4kman You shouldn't use a fixed date format when displaying a date to the user. The date should be displayed using date formatter dateStyle property (`.long`).

Comment: @LeoDabus I agree with this in most cases, however, the intent of the OP in this scenario is using a specific date formatting, regardless of the locale of the user.

Comment: I still disagree. Note that you have to set the locale to en_US_POSIX when using a fixed date format

Comment: @LeoDabus If the OP wants to display a localized month name but decides to keep this proprietary format, `en_US_POSIX` is not the option to choose.

Comment: Again I don't care what OP wants. He shouldn't force a certain date format to be displayed to the user. If the date will be localized to a different language it should be done correctly using dateStyle property.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: thanks for the answer! I found a wried case: on iPhone 11 missing the line `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") ` would cause `date` is nil, but the issue is not occur on iPhone 12 (and other newer iPhone)

Answer (score 2):

A `DateFormatter` can convert a string into a date only if the format of the date string matches the `dateFormat`—which isn’t the case in your example. For this reason it correctly responds with a `nil` reply.

Comment: Thanks @Tom E. For me "2021-10-14T11:40:26.000Z" this type of date need to use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" this Date format. Then converted to "dd-MM-yyyy" this format to get String Date